# Bootstrap 4 Compass Project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass, susy

I am getting in a muddle and need some plain speaking advice with setting up a project that will use both Bootstrap 4 and Compass.

My usual way of working is just Compass and I use the Susy grid system.
My typical project structure looks like this:

```
/css
/js
/img
/fonts
/sass
--/abstractions
--/base
--/components
--main.scss
```

I want to be able to integrate Bootstrap into this so that I can use some of its components to speed up my development of forms, tables, etc. But I don’t want or need the Bootstrap grid system for example. I also want to be able to easily customise the look and feel of the Bootstrap elements.

How do I best achieve this setup?

Answer (score 0):

To use Bootstrap features partially, you can access [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), the official Bootstrap site and download only the items you need. After download, simply add the files in your project and realize their link to their web pages.

I hope helped you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think getbootstrap.com is for Bootstrap 3 only. I am more interested in how to integrate Bootstrap 4 into my project making use of its SASS files and integrating it into the SASS of my compass project so that I can override and customise its variables etc.